# Fatal Error: Call to member function xpath to non-object AFTER uploading to provider

Tags: php, xpath

I'm trying to extract data from a tumblr XML-Feed and it works perfectly on my local MAMP-Server. However, having uploaded it to my provider's server I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object in 
/home/httpd/vhosts/anthronaut.net/subdomains/nico/httpdocs/scripts/tumblr.php 
on line 19
```

Here's the part of the code in question:

```
$request_url = "http://nicolasblandin.tumblr.com/api/read";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
$posts = $xml->xpath("/tumblr/posts/post");
```

My hunch is that the serverside settings need to be changed. I found one setting `allow_url_fopen`and set it to `true`, however with no success.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What do you get when you retrieve the URL using `wget`or `curl`? Is it a valid XML document?

Comment: Yes, `wget` retrieves a valid XML document. It also works perfectly on my local MAMP-Server.

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `simplexml_load_file` returns an *array* of type `SimpleXMLElement`. So, changing the third line of your code to

```
$posts = $xml[0]->xpath("/tumblr/posts/post");
```

seems to solve the issue. The real question is now: why does it actually work in the other case?

Comment: Good morning! Thanks for the hint, but unfortunately also this didn't help. However, in order to isolate the error, I just tried the script on a different server and it works, as it did on my local machine. So it must be an issue with my provider's PHP settings, I will dig into that. Thanks for the help!